# How can I split one band from 3 stacked layer image by ERDAS IMAGINE?

Tags: erdas-imagine

I have a 3 layers stacked image, each layer represents a band ratio for lithology extractions for geological purposes. I need to separate each layer separately 
how can I do this by using erdas imagine

Answer (score 1):

In model maker make a simple model by:

1. add a raster later variable and provide image name to be split
2. place a function object and link with raster input just provided as above.
3. double click on function object & now you will see a raster variable listed in top left corner & 3 more names (assuming 3 bands in raster) with suffix (band number)
4. Select the band you wand to separate.
5. Place a raster object and connect the function to this raster object.
6. Double click on raster & provide a name as well as data type for the raster output.
7. Run the model & you have a raster image with band you required